# How do I get calculate D1 and d1 in a multinomial processing tree model?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, statistics, recognition

I've just been reading [this paper](http://psycnet.apa.org/journals/rev/97/4/548/) and I am currently conducting an experiment for my undergraduate thesis. The experiment involves reality monitoring source memory judgments and I therefore want to use multinomial processing tree models (MPTM) to analyse the behavioral data.

In the article I linked above, they have an example under the heading "Reality monitoring" from an article by Johnson, Foley, and Leach (1988). They include the original 3x3 data table from their study, as well as a parameter estimate using MPTM. Can someone help me explain how they obtain those variables? For example, when I try to calculate D1 based on the original 3x3 data I get (87+8)/(87+8+25) = 0,79 and not 0,75 as is stated in their table.